# Tense agreement when one recent activity is interrupted by another

Tags: present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses, present-perfect-progressive

I wrote this sentence but I'm not convinced the tenses are correct.

> I've been waiting for this book for a few weeks, and it has just come out

In the first clause, I used present perfect continuous because it's an action that lasted for some time and finished recently. However, the activity is definitely finished - it got interrupted by the book's release - which makes me question it.

As for the second clause, you could argue that "just" in "it has just come out" refers to a specific point in the past and so past simple should be used. However, the fact that it came out is relevant to the present ("... so I'm about to go buy it"); therefore, I used present perfect simple.

Honestly, I'm not sure if either of them is correct. It almost seems like the whole sentence should be in the past

> I had been waiting for this book for a few weeks, and it was just released

But that doesn't sound right to me. It sounds like a neutral statement of fact that doesn't have bearing on the present.

Comment: If the book has only recently come out, I think your original version is acceptable - or you could say 'I had been waiting... and it has just come out".

Comment: I think "I had been waiting" makes sense since the activity is now finished. Just never thought about tenses interacting like that. Thanks @KateBunting!